# What do we know about the Black Speech of Mordor?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, languages, canon, tolkien-languages

We know the Ring Verse (Ash Nazg . . .), and single words like 'Ghâsh' (Fire). Do we know any more about *canonical* Black Speech?

Answer (score 16):

According to Tolkien himself:

> The Black Speech was not intentionally modeled on any style, but was
>   meant to be self consistent, very different from Elvish, yet organized
>   and expressive, as would be expected of a device of Sauron before his
>   complete corruption. It was evidently an agglutinative language. [...]
>   I have tried to play fair linguistically, and it is meant to have a
>   meaning not be a mere casual group of nasty noises
>
> "Words, Phrases and Passages in Various Tongues in The Lord of the Rings", Parma Eldalemberon 17, p. 11-12.

This is from an issue of a magazine which contained a collection of notes about the uses of his various invented languages as they occurred in *The Lord of the Rings*. [According to the editor](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Parma_Eldalamberon_17):

> Although Tolkien never completed the commentary as originally planned,
>   he retained the more cursory list of words and names from which he was
>   working; and he continued to compose further notes on the grammar and
>   history of the Elvish words and names in the story. Many of these were
>   placed together with "Words, Phrases and Passages," and the main
>   commentary has been supplemented by these notes in this edition.
>   Together these texts give the clearest picture we have of how Tolkien
>   conceived of his linguistic inventions in the forms they were revealed
>   to his readers.

So it's a lot more than just a single verse and some words, but a lot less than a complete language with fully-formed grammar and vocabulary.

Comment: Where do we know it from?

Comment: @MadTuy: the source is cited: Parma Eldalemberon is the name of the magazine, this is from issue no. 17, which was published in 2007

Comment: Sorry, I mean where do we know so many words from?

Comment: @MadTux: because they're in those notes that Tolkien wrote.

Comment: Here, because nobody else has mentioned this in all these years:  http://folk.uib.no/hnohf/blackspeech.htm

Answer (score 4):

### Not a lot

We have in total about [32 known words](https://eldamo.org/content/word-indexes/words-bs.html) in Tolkien's Black Speech. The majority are from *The Lord of the Rings*, both from the ring verse you cited, and also in the orcish curse in the Two Towers.

> 'Lie quiet, or I'll tickle you with this,' he hissed. 'Don't draw attention to yourself, or I may forget my orders. Curse the Isengarders! *Uglúk u bagronk sha pushdug Saruman-glob búbhosh skai*': he passed into a long angry speech in his own tongue that slowly died away into muttering and snarling.
> <sub>*The Lord of the Rings* - Book III - Chapter 3 - "The Uruk-Hai"</sub>

In addition, some other sources that have come to light later:

- Parma Eldabaron 17 contains an analysis of the ring inscription, written by JRR Tolkien, a letter Tolkien wrote in 1964 where he talks a bit about Black Speech and gives some example of its verb system, and various glosses Tolkien gave on the handful of Black Speech words found in LotR.
- There's a handful of glosses of some other Black Speech words published in *The History of Middle-earth*, *Unfinished Tales*, and *Letters of JRR Tolkien*.

All together the corpus is still very small and there is not a lot known.

Some resources you may find helpful:

- [Eldamo's database on Black Speech](https://eldamo.org/content/language-pages/lang-bs.html)
- [Analysis by Un4givenOrc](http://blackspeech.ru/index.php?page=2&lid=21&lang=en) (Note that while this website is devoted to a fan extension of the language, this page itself confines itself to just canonical Black Speech and is the best I've seen.)
- [Analysis by Helge Fauskanger](https://folk.uib.no/hnohf/orkish.htm) (Good, but written prior to the publication of PE#17, and so not up to date.)