# Does the Black Speech have a name?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, languages, tolkien-languages

Most sources seem to call the language of Sauron's servants the *Black Speech* and/or the language of Mordor, while other languages have their own names, such as Khuzdul, Quenya, and Sindarin. Does the Black Speech have an actual in-universe *name*, either in its own language or in another of the languages of Middle Earth?

Comment: Well, in very non-canon stuff there was "Melkian", but this was very early concept, AFAIR.

Comment: related https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60431/how-did-the-black-speech-come-about?rq=1 https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35012/what-do-we-know-about-the-black-speech-of-mordor

Comment: Note by the way that *Sinda* is itself a Quenya form; the Sindarin equivalent might be *Thend*.

Answer (score 14):

The Black Speech certainly has a name.  Sauron was the language inventor, and surely somewhere in his grammar notes he would have given it a name.  Tolkien never reveals a "proper" name nor offers a hint as to what it could be.  "B.S." is almost surely a sense-translation from the Westron name, and one would hazard the guess that its Elvish counterpart would be similarly constructed.

- In Letter 144<sup>[1]</sup>, he just calls it "Black Speech".
- Foster does not record a B.S. name for the language (though does hint that Sauron was, perhaps, something of a hack language inventor stating that B.S. could be based on Quenya)<sup>[2]</sup>.
- Similarly, Tyler does not record a name<sup>[3]</sup>.
- In *The Peoples of Middle-earth*, C.J.R.T. says "The Orcs had a language of their own, devised for them by the Dark Lord of old" and "It is said that the Black Speech was devised by Sauron in the Dark Years."<sup>[4]</sup>  Elsewhere in the same volume, a sentence is translated, but the language again is called "Black Speech".
- We shouldn't be surprised he never gave the B.S. a name other than the English / Westron moniker.  Letter 343 expresses Tolkien's gut reaction towards the hideous speech upon receiving as a gift a goblet with the Ring inscription engraved upon it.  In characteristic Tolkien fashion, perhaps, he used it as an ash tray<sup>[5]</sup>.

---

References:
1. *Letters of J.R.R. Tolkien*, 1981, p. 178;
2. *Complete Guide to Middle-earth*, 1978, p. 48;
3. *The Tolkien Companion*, 1976, p. 65;
4. *The Peoples of Middle-earth*, 1996, p. 65 pr. 16;
5. *Letters of J.R.R. Tolkien*, 1981, p. 422